# Why is $A/I^n A \cong \hat{A}/I^n \hat{A}$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $I \subset A$ a finitely generated ideal. Define $\hat{A} := \varprojlim A/I^n$.

What is the best way to proof that $A/I^nA \cong \hat{A}/I^n \hat{A}$ for all $n$?

Comment: Would that just come directly from the definition of the inverse limit?  Define $f_{ij}: A/I^j A \to A/I^i A$ as the standard homomorphisms.  Then, $\displaystyle \hat{A} = \left\{\vec{a} \in \prod_{n\ge 1} A/I^n A \mid a_i = f_{ij}(a_j)\text{ for all }1\le i \le j\right\}$.  Then, draw the commutative diagrams and do a little diagram chasing?  (I am not sure this is the best way, but it seems pretty straightforward to me).